# How to set custom paper size programmatically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing, browser, page-size

I want to print a bill from html page. The paper size will depends on list of orders (I can get the height from the div's height). I am ok with any one of the browser (ie, chrome, firefox). right now it prints letter size by default.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (hence comment, not answer) that Printer settings are protected and cannot be changed without the use of plugins such as Flash or Silverlight

Comment: is there any good flash or Silverlight plugin/example available?